# Get files production when refresh the website page

Tags: python, angular, flask, web, routes

When I refresh/reload my website (no issue on localhost, just on the online server) I get the "production files" via the browser

My server is on Flask, my app on Angular

**init**.py :

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def handle_angular_routes(e):
    return render_template("index.html") 

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def root():
    return render_template('index.html') # Return index.html
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [  { path: '', redirectTo: '/board', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'board', 
component: DashboardComponent 
},
{ path: 'stats', 
component: StatisticComponent 
},
{ path: 'servers', component: ServersComponent,
children: [
    { path: '', component: ServerListComponent },
    { path: 'data', component: ServerDataComponent },
  ],
},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

I don't see anything like this issue in google, please help

This is the screen when I reload the page :
[image]

EDIT :

my index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/static/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.e954dc3241c42566c194.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.359d5ee4682f20e936e9.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.bf99d438b005d57b2b31.js" defer></script><script src="scripts.63eb86643d8df48bd8fa.js" defer></script><script src="main.29f1e7124dfcbbc1987c.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us the content of `index.html`

Comment: I add in my publication now @Nour-AllahHussein